# Does Hotspot virtual machine support allocation on the stack

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

After the escape analysis, the variables did not escape, whether Hotspot implemented the on-stack allocation of the variables that did not escape

I'm not talking about a scalar substitution

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify JVM implementation to get specific answer, but in general answer is YES.

Comment: But openjdk doesn't have code that implements on-stack allocation, and where does it do it;  Where are the objects allocated on the stack stored, local variables?

Comment: You getting it other way around. Local variables are allocated on stack.

Comment: I mean the objects allocated on the stack, are they in the local variable table of the stack frame?

I'm sorry that my English is not very good, and the translation software I use may not be very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses a technique called scalar replacement. So the object isn't allocated on the stack, but the fields of the object are.

https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/18-scalar-replacement/